# why array is NULL in php?

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php    

class ffooo
{
    public $arr;

    function __construct()
    {
        $arr=array();
    }

    function add($val)
    {
        $arr[]=$val;
    }

    function get($ind)
    {
        return $arr[$ind];
    }
}

$cont=new ffooo();
$cont->add("derek",'chmo');
echo $cont->get(0);
var_dump($cont);
```

Can anybody explain me why my array $arr is NULL after method add($val)?
I try to echo array $arr in method "add",and in this method $arr contained come value;
but in another method it becomed NULL? 
What is the magic?I do't understand the logic(

Comment: You forgot to use $this inside the methods

Answer (score 1):

Because it is defined locally only. To use the class member, you must use $this;

```
$this->arr
```

Comment: oh...thank you...i did'nt know that in php it is so important...I,actually,write code on c#,and in c# it is not so important...thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you declare a variable `$arr` every time. And in every method it's just new, as functions have their own scope.

You need to set a property, like that: `$this->arr = array(...);`. Properties exist in object scope, so they are accessible from every method.

Answer (score 0):

You declared the function with one argument:

```
function add($val) {}
```

But pass to it two ones. And why do you use local copies of the class property in every function?
Correct your code before talking about magic :)

Comment: "Magic" is something happening that you don't understand. The OP obviously didn't understand how scope resolution works here, or the question would not have been asked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->arr` instead of `$arr` in all methods' bodies.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use `$this`, please see the code below.

```
<?php    

class ffooo
{
    public $arr;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->arr = array();
    }

    function add($val)
    {
        $this->arr[] = $val;
    }

    function get($ind)
    {
        return $this->arr[$ind];
    }
}

$cont=new ffooo();
$cont->add('derek');
echo $cont->get(0);
var_dump($cont);
```

Comment: And this `$cont->add("derek",'chmo');` is useless for the 2nd argument.

Comment: @AlexanderPalamarchuk, Nice information, i've done an update, thanks!